# How to start RabbitMQ listener after application boot?

Tags: grails, rabbitmq, amqp

Hi there i am using RabbitMQ inside my Grails application and am looking for ways on how to delay the start of the listeners. They are now started before the entire wiring of my application is done, so i would like to start them after startup.. any suggestion on how this can be done?

I am using the xml configuration for this..

```
<rabbit:listener-container connection-factory="connectionFactory" message converter="jsonMessageConverter" acknowledge="auto">
    <rabbit:listener queue-names="log.soap.in" ref="logSoapInListener" />
</rabbit:listener-container>
```

So when my grails application starts the context is started but it takes a while when all has been wired. So during the start of my application the listener is already called but is not able to handle the messages correctly.

```
class LogSoapListenerService implements MessageListener {

    LogSoapService logSoapService

    JsonMapper jsonMapper

    @Override
    void onMessage(Message message) {
        String body = new String(message.body, message.properties.contentEncoding ?: "UTF-8")
        logSoapService.process(body)
    }
}
```

Comment: presumably that is to do with the order of you code is it not?  If not I may have misunderstood and you might need to provide some more information.

Comment: Updated my question with code, the order of the code seems no problem. The listener is started before the whole Grails application is completely wired up and configured.

Comment: What type of listeners? Are you using the RabbitMQ plugin? The plugin [configures the message listener container](https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-rabbitmq/blob/master/src/groovy/org/grails/rabbitmq/RabbitServiceConfigurer.groovy#L188) so that it doesn't start automatically. It then starts them explicitly once the application context is ready.

Comment: I had some trouble with the latest RC1 of the plugin and decide to try a manual way. RC1 of the plugin has some serious issues that blocked my progress. As i would like to help along with the plugin i just have to limited knowledge on how to modify the existing plugin etc.. It would be great if RC2 or 1.0 would be released. When that happens i would be happy to use the plugin!!!

Answer (score 0):

I hit a similiar problem and this what I ended up added to the RabbitmqGrailsPlugin file, which I have a local version of as part of my project,

Inside of the `doWithApplicationContext` method, I changed,

```
// Now that the listener is properly configured, we can start it.
bean.start()
```

to

```
// Now that the listener is properly configured, we can start it.
def startDelay = application.config.rabbitmq.startDelay ?: 0
new Timer().runAfter(startDelay, {
    bean.start()
})
```

You then just need to configure, `rabbitmq.startDelay` to set whatever delay you want.

A more elegant solution would be to ensure that rabbitmq is loaded after other plugins, but Grails doesn't appear to have good support for that. See [Can I control plugin load order from outside a plugin in Grails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21146156/can-i-control-plugin-load-order-from-outside-a-plugin-in-grails)

Another solution, which is only available if you have the plugin installed locally, is to specify that the plugin load after whatever plugin is causing the issue,

For instance,

```
def loadAfter = ['services']
```

becomes

```
def loadAfter = ['services', 'converters', 'mail']
```

Comment: looking something similar in  java